# cannot infer type arguments for MFModel<>

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am working on a project for my thesis and can't wrap my head around the following problem...

I have several methods which implement interfaces and extend an abstract class (which implements parts of an interface) in some cases.

`MFModel` is a wrapper class which encapsulates my data model and several functions I need for some operations on a data stream.

```
class MFModel<D extends IDataModel<?, ?>> {
        public MFModel() {}
        public MFModel(final D dataModel, final IPredictor<D> predictor, final ILearner learner) {}
}
```

`RecDataModel` is one of my data model implementations.

```
class RecDataModel implements IDataModel<Map<Long, Map<Long, Double>>, IDataStats> {}
```

`BaselinePredictor` is one of the functions providing operations on my model's data, same goes for `NullLearner`.

```
class BaselinePredictor
    extends AbstractModularFunction<IPredictor<IDataModel<?, IDataStats>>>
    implements IPredictor<IDataModel<?, IDataStats>> {}

class NullLearner implements ILearner {}
```

`AbstractModularFunction<T>` is an abstract partial implementation an interface.

```
abstract class AbstractModularFunction<T> implements IModularFunction<T> {}
```

The following interfaces define the data contents of my model and provide the available functionality for my functions:

```
interface IDataModel<T, S> {}

interface IDataStats {}

interface IPredictor<D> extends IModularFunction<IPredictor<D>> {}

interface ILearner extends IModularFunction<ILearner> {}

interface IModularFunction<T> {}
```

While trying to instantiate a new `MFModel` I'm running into the following problem: first, if I instantiate the implemented versions of `ILearner` and `IPredictor<?>`, I don't get any warnings or errors:

```
MFModel<?> okayModel = new MFModel<>(new RecDataModel(), new BaselinePredictor(), new NullLearner());
```

However, if I try to use the interfaces, Eclipse throws a `cannot infer type arguments for MFModel<>` error:

```
ILearner learnerFunc = new NullLearner();
IPredictor<?> predictorFunc = new BaselinePredictor();
MFModel<?> problemModel = new MFModel<>(new RecDataModel(), predictorFunc, learnerFunc);
```

> Cannot infer type arguments for MFModel<>

I can get my code to compile and run if I omit the diamond operator, which in turn gives me the raw type warning then:

```
MFModel<?> warnModel = new MFModel(new RecDataModel(), predictorFunc, learnerFunc);
```

> Type safety: The constructor MFModel(IDataModel, IPredictor, ILearner) belongs to the raw type MFModel. References to generic type MFModel should be 
>        parameterized

As I dislike suppressing warnings (or accepting possible errors later on), I would like to know where the type argument error is originating from.

Here's a runnable snippet showing my problem: http://ideone.com/K5BaIN

I'm grateful for any input you can give me, as I must admit that these nested generics are quite hard to get a grip on for me. They lower the amount of casts and wrapper code required though, which is why I'd like to keep them. In addition, there are a few cases where I can't say for sure which kind of object I'll be getting due to modular code parts which can and should be easily exchanged for different implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Never use raw types

They are allowed for compatibility reasons, but using them would defeat the purpose of using generics in the first place as they violate almost all safety and abstraction achieved by using generics.

---

### 2. Use wildcards only when needed

Wildcard denote existential quantification over types variables, so they have a special purpose. They should not be used to avoid having to write (and think about) concrete types. If you don't wish to write types, you may enjoy languages with dynamic typing more.

Consider replacing

```
IPredictor<?> predictorFunc = new BaselinePredictor();
```

with either of the following two statements.

```
BaselinePredictor predictorFunc = new BaselinePredictor();
IPredictor<IDataModel<?, IDataStats>> predictorFunc = new BaselinePredictor();
```

---

Even

```
MFModel<?> okayModel = ...
```

would give rise to problems when you try to use `okayModel`.

---

### 3. Type inference is not magic

Compiler infers types of some expressions using types of other expressions. If you refuse to provide concrete type of anything, type inference would become impossible.

In the following code,

```
ILearner learnerFunc = new NullLearner();
IPredictor<?> predictorFunc = new BaselinePredictor();
MFModel<?> problemModel = new MFModel<>(new RecDataModel(), predictorFunc, learnerFunc);
```

- You refuse to give compiler concrete type arguments of `predictorFunc` variable.
- You refuse to give compiler concrete type arguments of `MFModel` constructor.
- You refuse to give compiler concrete type arguments of `problemModel` variable.

So the following error is justified.

> Cannot infer type arguments for MFModel<>

---

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in depth explanation, it helped me a lot seeing the cause of my problem. I totally agree with your first point, which is why I've asked this question in the first place. I went with the following, as I'm using a registry which holds the available functions and delegates instantiation to a factory:  `IPredictor<IDataModel<?, IDataStats>> predictorFunc = PredictorRegistry.createFunction(
    AggregationFunctionParseOptionsHelper.getFunctionParameterAsString(parameters, FUNC_PREDICT));`

Comment: As a follow up: I'm also removing wildcards where possible, as I have a few instances where I can guarantee the underlying type of parameter, i.e. `MFModel<IDataModel<?, IDataStats>> factorModel = ...`. I can't say for sure what type the first parameter will have but I can give the second parameter. Same goes for `public class MFModel<D extends IDataModel<?, IDataStats>>`. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Does your code compile without errors/warnings now?

Comment: It does (some for now unused loggers)! Thanks :)